# How To Add Empty Row To DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using JQuery DataTables and attempting to add an empty row to the DataTable.  I have the code below but a new empty row is not added.

How do I need to re-write this so that an empty row is added?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnCheck").click(function () {
        var table = $('#data').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print' ],
            "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://localhost:44328/api/employee-data',
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (data) {
                            var o = {"data":[]};
                            for(var i in data.data)
                            {
                                var row = [data.data[i].empID,data.data[i].empSA];
                                o.data.push(row);
                            }
                            callback(o);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    });
        $('#AddRow').on('click', function () {
        var t = $('#data').DataTable();
        t.row.add( [] ).draw();
    } );
    $('#AddRow').click();
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**
I edited the code to this, but now I get multiple errors in the Console....so I must have mis-understood...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var table;
    $("#btnCheck").click(function () {
        $('#data').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print' ],
            "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://localhost:44328/api/employee-data',
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (data) {
                            var o = {"data":[]};
                            for(var i in data.data)
                            {
                                var row = [data.data[i].empID,data.data[i].empSA];
                                o.data.push(row);
                            }
                            callback(o);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    });
        $('#AddRow').on('click', function () {
        table.row.add( [] ).draw();
    } );
    $('#AddRow').click();
});
</script>
```

**Edit 2**
This is my HTML

```
<div id="dtTapCount">
<table id="data" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>EmpID</th>
        <th>EmpSA</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use the `var table`, declare out of the click event so that it can be reused

Comment: if I declare var table; how do I then set table = #data so both methods work?

Comment: the #data it's the control <table> on the HTML, but when you store the `var table` you're using the DataTable API. So you don't need to call the DataTable function again.

Comment: Can you post the HTML where #data is

Comment: posted HTML where #data

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiate the `var table` outside of the scope.
And in the `AddRow` event call it to add the row. 
Go to the [DataTables documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) there's more information about how to add rows.

```
var table;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnCheck").click(function () {
        table = $('#data').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print' ],
            "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://localhost:44328/api/employee-data',
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var o = {"data":[]};
                        for(var i in data.data)
                        {
                            var row = [data.data[i].location,data.data[i].tapCount];
                            o.data.push(row);
                        }
                        callback(o);
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    });
    $('#AddRow').on('click', function () {
        table.row.add(['' /* Location */, 0 /*Tap count */]).draw();
    });
    //$('#AddRow').click(); This is going to be called when AddRow button pressed.
});
```

Comment: should it be let table; or var table;

Comment: This gives me an error in console of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined`

Comment: what version of datatables are you using?

Comment: Make sure you're using the last version of jQuery DataTables https://datatables.net/download/

Comment: I believe i am using the latest version....here is screenshot of my https://ibb.co/HnXmSJp

Comment: What are the errors? I think I got what are you doing wrong let me edit my post

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined - i get the error on page load --- hten on the button press event I get this pop-up DataTables warning: table id=data - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 220, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: Issue still persists.  I believe it is because table is being declared in the JavaScrip but it is not being assigned until the actual button click event.